# Issue with News Extension Version 11.1 in TYPO3 12 - Undeclared Arguments in PageViewHelper

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-12.x

I'm trying to implement a newssystem with said news extension for my website. I implemented it successfully. Writing News works, categorizing works, tagging works, and reading the news posts works also. The posts even display the tags itself. But when I'm trying to use the taglist feature I get the following error:

> (1/1) TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Exception
>
> Undeclared arguments passed to ViewHelper TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Link\PageViewHelper: addQueryStringMethod. Valid arguments are: additionalAttributes, data, aria, class, dir, id, lang, style, title, accesskey, tabindex, onclick, target, rel, pageUid, pageType, noCache, language, section, linkAccessRestrictedPages, additionalParams, absolute, addQueryString, argumentsToBeExcludedFromQueryString

When disabling the taglist the error goes away immediately. Anyone knows what could be the problem here? As I said I'm using Typo3 12 and news 11.1 in composer mode using ddev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to a leftover in one of the templates, where a deprecated (v11) and removed (v12) ViewHelper argument is used.

The problem will most likely be fixed in the upcoming version. See this https://github.com/georgringer/news/pull/2160 pull request for an intermediate solution. You basically just have to remove `addQueryStringMethod="GET"` in the template file `Resources/Private/Templates/Styles/Twb5/Templates/Tag/List.html`